# $h\circ f=h\circ g$ for every function $h:T\rightarrow U$ where the set U has atleast two elements. Then $f=g$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Let $f,g:S\rightarrow T$ , and let $h\circ f=h\circ g$ for every function $h:T\rightarrow U$ where the set U has atleast two elements. Then $f=g$.

Comment: I am trying to prove this. I think, we can prove this by contradiction forcing the U to contain a single element. Please share your ideas about the proof.

Comment: This statement is true, and the proof is straight forward if h is one-to-one and U is any set .

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\exists x \in S$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$. Since $U$ has at least two elements we can choose a function $h: T \rightarrow S$ such that $h(f(x)) \neq h(g(x))$. But this contradicts the assumption.